# ZF2 - form fieldset

Tags: forms, zend-framework2, fieldset

I'm working on a Form with a Fieldset in it and i can't get the form to work correct with the hydrator.

What i have:

**Form**
  Base.php
    namespace Cms\Form\Cms;

```
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;
use Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService;
use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\Form\Fieldset;

use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ObjectProperty as ObjectPropertyHydrator;


public function __construct( ) {

$this->setAttribute('method', 'post')
     ->setHydrator(new ObjectPropertyHydrator(false)); 

$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'id',
    'type' => 'Hidden',
));
$this->add(array(
      'name' => 'title',
      'type' => 'Text',
      'required' => true,
      'options' => array(
          'label' => _('Menu titel'),
      ),
));
$meta = new \Cms\Form\Cms\Meta('meta');
$meta->setUseAsBaseFieldset(false);
$this->add($meta);
```

Meta.php

```
public function __construct($name = null)
{
     parent::__construct('meta');
     $this->setHydrator(new ObjectPropertyHydrator(false)) 
          ->setObject(new \Cms\Entity\MetaEntity());

     $this->setLabel('Meta');

     $this->add(array(
          'name' => 'seo_meta_title',
          'type' => 'Text',
          'options' => array(
             'label' => _('Title'),
          ),
     ));

      }
```

**Controller**
    ....

```
$cms = $this->getCmsable()->byId($id);

$form = new Base( 'add' );
$form->bind($cms);
```

The form worked fine until i added the extra fieldset.
If i use the setUseAsBaseFieldset option, true->fieldset field is only set
false-> only the main form is set.

I checked all the data and it is present.

I think it has something to do with the hydrator.
Can somebody give me some advice here?

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't get your problem exactly, what did you mean by the last part "If i use the setUseAsBaseFieldset option, true->fieldset field is only set false-> only the main form is set."
But [here](http://www.masterzendframework.com/zend-framework/simple-zend-framework-2-forms) is a working example of same implementation i.e. fieldset and ObjectPropertyHydrator. 
hope it helps

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: @AndrewStubbs which part of "working example of same implementation i.e. fieldset and ObjectPropertyHydrator" u couldnt get?? I wrote the statement because thats what the link is about. what more context do you need? i dont care much that you voted it down but that was...

Comment: **Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline**. Your post will be completely useless if the remote resource changes

Comment: Yes, I understand that **the link** potentially leads to a full example of the solution. However, if *that website goes down*, your Answer **by itself** won't help answer the question. By *quote the most relevant part*, it means **put the actual solution in your Answer**, as well as the link to the source.